# Subset data frame if two columns combined match two other columns exactly

Tags: r

I have data similar to this

```
x1 <- data.frame(state = c("FL","FL","TX","TX"), county = c("Duval","Columbia","Dallam","Dimmit"))
x2 <- data.frame(state = c("FL","FL","FL","TX","TX","TX"), county = c("Duval","Columbia","Pinellas","Dallam","Dimmit","Duval"), UR = c(4,5,7,4,6,3))

x3 <- subset(x2, county %in% x1$county & state %in% x1$state)
```

The result I want are the 4 counties in x1 matched with their assigned UR from x2. My approach doesn't get rid of counties with the same name appearing in different states. So is there an option so that I can filter only if state + county combined match?

Comment: Try looking up: `?merge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a left join:

```
> library(dplyr)
> left_join(x1, x2, by = c('state', 'county'))
  state   county UR
1    FL    Duval  4
2    FL Columbia  5
3    TX   Dallam  4
4    TX   Dimmit  6
```

Or using `merge` from base R:

```
> merge(x1, x2, all.x = T)
  state   county UR
1    FL Columbia  5
2    FL    Duval  4
3    TX   Dallam  4
4    TX   Dimmit  6
```

Comment: Nice, that's exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x2)[x1, on = .(state, county)]
#   state   county UR
#1:    FL    Duval  4
#2:    FL Columbia  5
#3:    TX   Dallam  4
#4:    TX   Dimmit  6
```